# how can we in dart make an instance of Future by its factories constructors even if it is an abstract class?

Tags: dart

how can we in dart make an instance of Future by its factories constructors even if it is an abstract class?

```
factory Future(FutureOr<T> computation()) {
  _Future<T> result = new _Future<T>();
  Timer.run(() {
    try {
      result._complete(computation());
    } catch (e, s) {
      _completeWithErrorCallback(result, e, s);
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: A `factory` constructor can return a subtype (https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors). `_Future` is a concrete implementation of `Future` (https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/0180af250ff518cc0fa494a4eb484ce11ec1e62c/sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart#L211).

Comment: the factory constructor returns _future which is a sub class implementing Future so it can return an instance of it.